# Add a single point in plot with scaled and offset axes?

Tags: r, plot, point

I have the next code which represents a plot.

```
x1<-0:200
a1<-dnorm(x1,88.24,15)
b1<-dnorm(x1,92,16)
c1<-dnorm(x1,104,15)

x2<-400:1200
a2<-dnorm(x2,747.88,65.9792)
c2<-dnorm(x2,835,117)

scale<-range(pretty(range(a1,a2,b1,c1,c2)))

remap<-function(x, to, from=range(x)) {
    (x-from[1]) / (from[2]-from[1]) * (to[2]-to[1]) + to[1] 
}

plot(NA, NA, xaxt="n", yaxt="n", type="n", xlim=scale, ylim=scale, xlab="X", ylab="Y")

rect(remap(83, scale, range(x1)), scale[1],
     remap(93, scale, range(x1)), scale[2], col="#ff606025", lty=0)
rect(remap(82, scale, range(x1)), scale[1],
     remap(102, scale, range(x1)), scale[2], col="#3ca90025", lty=0)
rect(remap(67, scale, range(x1)), scale[1],
     remap(141, scale, range(x1)), scale[2], col="#3847ea25", lty=0)
rect(scale[1], remap(729, scale, range(x2)),
     scale[2], remap(767, scale, range(x2)), col="#ff606025", lty=0)
rect(scale[1], remap(544, scale, range(x2)),
     scale[2], remap(1126, scale, range(x2)), col="#3847ea25", lty=0)

lines(remap(x1,scale), a1, col="#ff6060", lwd=2)
lines(remap(x1,scale), b1, col="#3ca900", lwd=2)
lines(remap(x1,scale), c1, col="#3847ea", lwd=2)

lines(scale[2]-a2, remap(x2,scale), col="#ff6060", lwd=2)
lines(scale[2]-c2, remap(x2,scale), col="#3847ea", lwd=2)

axis(2); axis(3)
axis(1, at=remap(pretty(x1), scale), pretty(x1))
axis(4, at=remap(pretty(x2), scale), pretty(x2))
```

You can see a representation of what is seen below:
[image]

How can I add a single point in this plot? For example, when the point is X=100 and Y=600.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe is such a common question what I am trying to know, at least when viewing the code here. But I tried several times the function points with no succeed and I don't know what's wrong. I tried using points(100,600,pch=16) but I cannot see the point in the previous plot.

Comment: Did you try changing colors or locations etc, as 100,600 may be obscured by another color which would hide the point.

Comment: You have to rescale the coordinates of the point, as you did for the lines and the rectangles. `par()$usr` (i.e. the limits of the plot) gives `[1] -0.0012  0.0312 -0.0012  0.0312`.

Comment: Not really, however, the background bars have an opacity of 25%. So, even if the point falls within those colored areas (which is the case), I would expect to see the point.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. However, I still cannot see the point and I don't know how to include you code (Pascal) in mine to see the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
points( x=100*diff(scale)/diff(range(x1)), #could also use remap(100, scale, range(x1))
        y=remap(600, scale, range(x2) ), 
    col="red", cex=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate dataset with a single point, or a query on the existing dataset that returns a single point in a dataset, and pass this to the `points` function.

See the points function here: http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/graphics/points

Comment: Mike, could you please tell me the code that must be added above to represent a point with the next coordinates? X=100 and Y=600? I revised the link you pasted but I still don't understand it completely. Thanks